# How to do a number keypad in java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, numeric-keypad

I trying to figure out how to do a number keypad in java. I'm recently started using java, still have so much to learn. The following is what I came up with so far but it only returns one char at a time. Still researching this, but would really appreciate any assistance..thanks

```
currentButton = (JButton)event.getSource();
itemQuantity = currentButton.getText().charAt(0) - '0';
```

Comment: I am not suppose to use the keyboard

Comment: Are you trying to create a virtual keyboard on screen for just numbers or are you trying to read key presses on the number pad of a real keyboard?

Comment: Hi Pimaster - Its a virtual number pad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using the button's text as the value of one digit in a number  representing `itemQuantity`. Each time a button is pressed, you should append that button's digit to a string:

```
String currentString = "";
currentString += currentButton.getText();
```

Then you can get the numeric value as @user1804740 suggests:

```
itemQuantity = Integer.parseInt(currentString);
```

Note, you'll have to handle any `NumberFormatException` thrown by the conversion.

Comment: Also consider `StringBuilder` for `currentString`.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit vague to me.

I hope Integer.parseInt("string") and/or Double.parseDouble("string") work for you.

Comment: Also consider `Integer.valueOf()`.